# How to get address of a symbol in a shared library when provided address of the library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dlopen, dlsym

I am learning about working with shared libraries in C/C++ on Linux. I encountered a little problem that I don't know how to solve.

Let's say I have a shared library and an executable. However I don't know the library's name or file location (so I can't `dlopen` it). I can only find the address range where the library is mapped into my executable's memory.

Is there a way to programmatically get either the handle of the library (something like `handle = dlopen(library_address)`) or offset of a symbol within the library (something like `address = dlsym(library_address, symbol_name)`)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you knew the library's name, you could just call `dlopen` again.

From the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html):

> If the same shared object is loaded again with `dlopen()`, the same object handle is returned.

To discover the loaded modules, you can use [`dl_iterate_phdr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dl_iterate_phdr.3.html).

You can also use [`dladdr()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dladdr.3.html) to inquire about a specific address.

Comment: And if I never knew the name? Is there a way to just get the handle from the address?

Comment: @TopperHarley On Linux you can open `/proc/self/maps` and use the address to find the mapping, which will give you the shared object's name.  Then use the name to get the handle with [`dlopen( ..., RTLD_NOLOAD );](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html).

Comment: @AndrewHenle One problem with this is that `/proc/self/maps` is sometimes not available, especially in buildroots.